# How can I center only the viewImage in a compundText and leave the text itself aligned to it parent bottom?

Tags: android, layout, center

I want to fix a bu of non centered image in compoundText view.

[image]

In a compound textView, the code adds an image with size 6x10 dp

```
TextViewCompat.setCompoundDrawablesRelative(targetTextView, null, null, drawable, null);
```

I want the image to be (almost) centered vertically to the text view + 1 sp length lower than the center.

So in each textView xml I added

```
      android:gravity="center_vertical"
```

I have tried to create a canvas with height 8 x 10 and center it to the text view and then set the drawable bounds to (0,1sp, 10, 8-1sp)

but it seems the text view moved upwords relative to its position before centering `android:gravity="center_vertical"`

[image]

How can I center only the viewImage in a compundText and leave the text itself aligned to it parent bottom?

```
  private void tintAndAddPadding(

...


      @DrawableRes int drawableId, @ColorRes int colorId) {
    Drawable drawable =
        Preconditions.checkNotNull(AppCompatResources.getDrawable(getContext(), drawableId));
    Drawable drawableWithTint = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable);
    DrawableCompat.setTint(
        drawableWithTint.mutate(), getContext().getResources().getColor(colorId));
    // Bitmap dimensions sets the canvas dimensions
    Bitmap bitmap =
        Bitmap.createBitmap(
            getContext()
                .getResources()
                .getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.account_menu_collapse_expand_width),
            getContext()
                .getResources()
                .getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.account_menu_collapse_expand_canvas_height),
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

    // Drawable bounds should be all 4 coordinates on the canvas to draw on.
    // This implies the drawable width and height.
    drawableWithTint.setBounds(
        0,
        getContext()
            .getResources()
            .getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.account_menu_collapse_expand_top_padding)
        , canvas.getWidth(),
        canvas.getHeight() -
            getContext()
                .getResources()
                .getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.account_menu_collapse_expand_top_padding));
    drawableWithTint.draw(canvas);

   TextViewCompat.setCompoundDrawablesRelative(targetTextView, null, null, drawableWithTint, null);
    // Padding between text and drawable
    targetTextView.setCompoundDrawablePadding(
        getContext()
            .getResources()
            .getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.account_menu_collapse_expand_left_padding))
  }
```

I know i can use relativeLayout, but my team encourages me to use compoundText nevertheless.

Comment: You'll probably need to extend TextView to make your own implementation that does what you want. However, a FrameLayout with an ImageView centered vertically and a TextView with the gravity set to `bottom` would be the easiest and probably cleanest way to do this.

Comment: @pskink I have made the question simpler. I repost the simpler because no one could understand the previous one. I use the bitmap to set the size of the canvas (in its ctor) and that's it.

Comment: @pskink this canvas which the drawable is drawn on
`Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);` and `drawableWithTint.draw(canvas);`

Comment: @pskink i thought every drawable has to have canvas to draw on. even when the corrdinates are negative

Comment: `TextView`  has its own `Canvas`, not `Drawable` and `TextView` uses its own canvas and calls `drawableWithTint.draw()` method with that canvas - it is done in `View#onDraw(Canvas)` method

Comment: @pskink talking about centering, is it possible to center-vertically only the drawable relative to the textView and leave the text not centered vertically relative to its textView?

Comment: by default (when used with bounds 0, 0, w, h) right compound drawable is centered vertically, so i'm afraid i dont understand the question...

Comment: @pskink i want the text to be aligned to its textView's bottom. and the image to be vertically-centered to its textview.  if I put "gravity" in the textView xml it align both of them. I can calculate the textView height for the image bounds, but then i have to use TreeObserver

Comment: @pskink plus when i use the negative bounds, the drawable will be clipped. I want to add padding on top. or i didn't get you

Comment: https://codeshare.io/aVOWyR the text is on the bottom of `TextView` and the drawable is vertically centered

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179684/discussion-between-elad-benda-and-pskink).